# Collection of elements painted each for achieving a gradient from first element to last

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, colors

I'm plotting a histogram of a grayscale image using an array of 256 values. Im doing so by creating my own chart with 256 vertical rectangles (columns). My aim is that first rectangle fill color to be red and the last rectangle to be blue. All the rectangles in between to be filled with a solid color which will make the transition from the first (red) to last (blue) smooth, like achiving a gradient with a rectangle step in changing the color.

When you look to the code, you can see that I'm able to fetch the index value of each element (rectangle) from the array. This is encapsulated in AlternationIndex and I'm thinking that the solution should use this in order to manipulate the Fill color value. Is it possible than to have a pure XAML solution for this ?

So the transition should look something like:

[image]

Here is my XAML code

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding HistogramValues}" AlternationCount="{Binding Path=HistogramValues.Count}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Height="{Binding}" ToolTip="{Binding Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContentPresenter}}" Width="3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Fill="Black"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Where in view model I have:

```
public float[] HistogramValues { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a custom converter which will pass an AlternationIndex & AlternationCount as parameters, and which spits out the color.

You can do linear interpolation between colors given those two parameters:

```
R = firstCol.R * p + secondCol.R * (1 - p)
```

The formula is quite easy, `firstCol` is the start color, `secondCol` is the end color.

p stands for current percentage, which can be calculated as `currentAlternationIndex / AlternationCount`.

You can do such calculation for each component(R, G, B), and your converter can return `SolidColorBrush` with concrete components.

Not sure though what you mean by pure Xaml solution. If you mean no converters, then there probably isn't one that is decent enough to mention here.

The other solution is to switch from height model into line model. Instead of ItemsControl, perhaps you can use Polyline to draw the data & then the gradient problem will be trivial.

Comment: Yeah, your solution seems a good one. By pure XAML I was thinking for a solution without a converter yes. And I don't want to represent the histogram as a polygon due to my functionality you can see from the XAML, which is, when I mouse over a rectangle, I can find the corresponding pixel it represents (the corresponding pixel is the index in the histogram values array). Having this functionality with a polygon seems really hard, but as you said, gradient problem will be trivial.

Comment: I never implemented converters :/ ... Dont know where to start. Maybe you are kind enough to give me some code which would work :). I have the View in a HystogramView.xaml and the ViewModel in HystogramViewModel.cs. The Converter should be in HystogramView.xaml.cs ?

Comment: @Chris: See if this helps you: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2154/simple-example-of-multibinding-and-imultivalueconverter-in-mvvm-wrt-wp